# Make one query from 2 complex queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I have confusion about making 2 queries into 1 query because those queries are too complex for me.
This is my first query.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(s1.kode_barang, s2.kode_barang) AS kode_barang,
    COALESCE(s1.nama, s2.nama) AS nama,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) AS sisa_JUNI,
    COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS masuk_JULI,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) + COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s2.max_tanggal,
            s2.kode_barang,
            s1.nama,
            s2.sisa
        FROM
            ws_fh.simas_barang s1
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                FROM
                    ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            kode_barang,
                            MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal,
                            created_at
                        FROM
                            ws_fh.simas_mutasi
                        WHERE
                            tanggal BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30'
                        GROUP BY
                            kode_barang
                    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang
                    AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
                GROUP BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                ORDER BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at DESC
            ) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = s1.id
        WHERE
            s1.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        GROUP BY
            s2.kode_barang
    ) s1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sm.tanggal,
        sm.kode_barang,
        sb.nama,
        SUM(sm.jumlah) AS total_jumlah
    FROM
        ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
        JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
    WHERE
        sb.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengeluarkan stok'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengubah barang'
        AND sm.tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
    GROUP BY
        sb.nama
) s2 ON s1.nama = s2.nama

UNION

SELECT
    COALESCE(s1.kode_barang, s2.kode_barang) AS kode_barang,
    COALESCE(s1.nama, s2.nama) AS nama,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) AS sisa,
    COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total_jumlah,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) + COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s2.max_tanggal,
            s2.kode_barang,
            s1.nama,
            s2.sisa
        FROM
            ws_fh.simas_barang s1
            RIGHT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                FROM
                    ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            kode_barang,
                            MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal,
                            created_at
                        FROM
                            ws_fh.simas_mutasi
                        WHERE
                            tanggal BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30'
                        GROUP BY
                            kode_barang
                    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang
                    AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
                GROUP BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                ORDER BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at DESC
            ) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = s1.id
        WHERE
            s1.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        GROUP BY
            s2.kode_barang
    ) s1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sm.tanggal,
        sm.kode_barang,
        sb.nama,
        SUM(sm.jumlah) AS total_jumlah,
        sm.kegiatan
    FROM
        ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
        JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
    WHERE
        sb.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengeluarkan stok'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengubah barang'
        AND sm.tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
    GROUP BY
        sb.nama
) s2 ON s1.nama = s2.nama
WHERE
    s1.nama IS NULL
ORDER BY
    nama;
```

This is my second query.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sm.kode_barang, s1.id) AS kode_barang, 
COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama) AS nama, 
SUM(sm.jumlah) AS keluar_JULI, 
s2.sisa AS sisa_JULI
FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
LEFT JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sm1.kode_barang, sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal, sm1.created_at, sm1.sisa
    FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
    JOIN (
        SELECT kode_barang, MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal, created_at
        FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi
        WHERE tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
        GROUP BY kode_barang
    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
    GROUP BY sm1.kode_barang, sm1.created_at, sm1.sisa
    ORDER BY sm1.kode_barang, sm1.created_at DESC
) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = sb.id
RIGHT JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang s1 ON s1.id = s2.kode_barang
WHERE COALESCE(sb.jenis, s1.jenis) = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
GROUP BY COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama)
HAVING keluar_JULI IS NOT NULL AND sisa_JULI IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama);
```

I wanted to make it all into one query. Use group by for "nama" so the same "nama" from first query and second query would be in the same row. If "nama" from the first query is not matching with "nama" in the second query then display it in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will need a FULL OUTER JOIN, which MySQL doesn't support, with MySQL 8 it gets at least somewhat more readable

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT
    COALESCE(s1.kode_barang, s2.kode_barang) AS kode_barang,
    COALESCE(s1.nama, s2.nama) AS nama,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) AS sisa_JUNI,
    COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS masuk_JULI,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) + COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s2.max_tanggal,
            s2.kode_barang,
            s1.nama,
            s2.sisa
        FROM
            ws_fh.simas_barang s1
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                FROM
                    ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            kode_barang,
                            MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal,
                            created_at
                        FROM
                            ws_fh.simas_mutasi
                        WHERE
                            tanggal BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30'
                        GROUP BY
                            kode_barang
                    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang
                    AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
                GROUP BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                ORDER BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at DESC
            ) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = s1.id
        WHERE
            s1.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        GROUP BY
            s2.kode_barang
    ) s1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sm.tanggal,
        sm.kode_barang,
        sb.nama,
        SUM(sm.jumlah) AS total_jumlah
    FROM
        ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
        JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
    WHERE
        sb.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengeluarkan stok'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengubah barang'
        AND sm.tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
    GROUP BY
        sb.nama
) s2 ON s1.nama = s2.nama

UNION

SELECT
    COALESCE(s1.kode_barang, s2.kode_barang) AS kode_barang,
    COALESCE(s1.nama, s2.nama) AS nama,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) AS sisa,
    COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total_jumlah,
    COALESCE(s1.sisa, 0) + COALESCE(s2.total_jumlah, 0) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s2.max_tanggal,
            s2.kode_barang,
            s1.nama,
            s2.sisa
        FROM
            ws_fh.simas_barang s1
            RIGHT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                FROM
                    ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            kode_barang,
                            MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal,
                            created_at
                        FROM
                            ws_fh.simas_mutasi
                        WHERE
                            tanggal BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30'
                        GROUP BY
                            kode_barang
                    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang
                    AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
                GROUP BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at,
                    sm1.sisa
                ORDER BY
                    sm1.kode_barang,
                    sm1.created_at DESC
            ) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = s1.id
        WHERE
            s1.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        GROUP BY
            s2.kode_barang
    ) s1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sm.tanggal,
        sm.kode_barang,
        sb.nama,
        SUM(sm.jumlah) AS total_jumlah,
        sm.kegiatan
    FROM
        ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
        JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
    WHERE
        sb.jenis = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengeluarkan stok'
        AND sm.kegiatan != 'mengubah barang'
        AND sm.tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
    GROUP BY
        sb.nama
) s2 ON s1.nama = s2.nama
WHERE
    s1.nama IS NULL
ORDER BY
    nama),
    CTE2 AS(
    SELECT COALESCE(sm.kode_barang, s1.id) AS kode_barang, 
COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama) AS nama, 
SUM(sm.jumlah) AS keluar_JULI, 
s2.sisa AS sisa_JULI
FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm
LEFT JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang sb ON sb.id = sm.kode_barang
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sm1.kode_barang, sm1.tanggal AS max_tanggal, sm1.created_at, sm1.sisa
    FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi sm1
    JOIN (
        SELECT kode_barang, MAX(tanggal) AS max_tanggal, created_at
        FROM ws_fh.simas_mutasi
        WHERE tanggal BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
        GROUP BY kode_barang
    ) sm2 ON sm2.kode_barang = sm1.kode_barang AND sm2.max_tanggal = sm1.tanggal
    GROUP BY sm1.kode_barang, sm1.created_at, sm1.sisa
    ORDER BY sm1.kode_barang, sm1.created_at DESC
) s2 ON s2.kode_barang = sb.id
RIGHT JOIN ws_fh.simas_barang s1 ON s1.id = s2.kode_barang
WHERE COALESCE(sb.jenis, s1.jenis) = 'ATK DAN SEJENISNYA'
GROUP BY COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama)
HAVING keluar_JULI IS NOT NULL AND sisa_JULI IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY COALESCE(sb.nama, s1.nama))
    SELECT COALESCE(CTE1.kode_barang,CTE1.kode_barang) kode_barang,COALESCE(CTE1.nama,CTE1.nama) nama,
    sisa_JUNI,masuk_JULI, keluar_JULI,sisa_JULI,total
    FROM CTE1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.kode_barang = CTE2.kode_barang
    UNION
SELECT COALESCE(CTE1.kode_barang,CTE1.kode_barang),COALESCE(CTE1.nama,CTE1.nama),
    sisa_JUNI,masuk_JULI, keluar_JULI,sisa_JULI,total
    FROM CTE2 LEFT JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.kode_barang = CTE2.kode_barang
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question :) I modified a  lil bit of your query and the result works like what I want.

Comment: and why didn't you accept the answer?